# Borderless form shows borders for a moment when shown inside an mdi container

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, windows-xp, formborderstyle

**Update (2011-01-17):**

I am creating a form with `FormBorderStyle=None` inside an MdiContainer.
When I show the first form, even if it has already been created, for a fraction of a second it appears with the blue border of a normal form, then it's reverted.

With the following sample, clicking once and again on button1, it will show this behavior from time to time, although it's for a very brief lapse of time, so i guess it will be hard to see in a very fast machine; however, in my production code with 3rd party .net controls, it's shown for a lot more time.

To try this, just create a new project, and a windows form called Form2, add a button to Form1, add the events Form1_Load and button1_Click, and paste the code. Then, click button1 for a while.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form.Visible = !form.Visible;
        form.MdiParent = this;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        form = new Form2();
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

This is language agnostic, so, please, don't change my tags without a good reason.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this with the exact same form inheritance chain that you describe. Compiled in VS 2008 (I don't have VS 2005, but this shouldn't be relevant) against version 3.0 of the .NET FW running under Windows XP. Something else is wrong. Post the code in the constructor methods for each of the forms in the inheritance chain.

Comment: As long as you use the constructor this should *not* happen.  You'll need to provide a small repro project that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: I have tested it in vs2010 agains FW versions 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0, and I have enabled optimizations, just in case. I'll post the code of the simplest form right now.

Comment: [Unrelated: You're coding with "Option Strict" off. Turn it on (in the project properties), and fix the compiler errors. Keep it on for all projects in VB.NET.] Also, I tried it again, creating a blank project with two classes containing the code you posted above, added the controls that were referenced in the code to make it compile, set the `FormBorderStyle` to "None" on `FormLogin` in the designer, and ran it on a blank Windows XP virtual machine. I still don't see a flash of the form's borders. I suspect the problem is with your computer's graphics card. Can you try another computer?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Cody; Coming from vb6 and C++, I thought that 'Option Explicit' was enough. I will try another computer, however I don't think the graphics card is the problem... It's a GeForce 8800 GTX. I will try to update the drivers, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If there's something slowing down your main UI thread, Windows will paint the form using default values (At least in the DVM world of Vista/Windows 7) until your thread becomes responsive again. Check to make sure your UI thread isn't waiting on some other threads or doing some heavy processing when the form is first shown.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my application and I added the following line as the first line in Form-Load Function to fix the problem

this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

Answer (score 0):

It may depend wether you are changing the FormBorderStyle on Load, in a constructor, or on Shown. Best to do it in constructor (InitializeComponents method).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am changing it in the designer, so yes, it's really changing in InitializeComponents.

Comment: Do You use DoubleBuffering for that Form?

Comment: No, but I have changed it and doesn't make any difference.